# Change the image for a certain URL

Tags: images, urls, media-library, dashboard

Currently we have an image at url /wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2014/07/filename.jpg

The image contains incorrect information, and we've already sent emails out containing links to this image. We'd like to swap the old image with a new, corrected version, but keep the URL exactly the same.

I tried deleting the image at this location, then uploading a new one with the exact same filename, but when I upload the image, WordPress automatically inserts the old image instead. It's very odd.

EDIT: It could be a caching issue of sorts. The new image is loading now in the HTML emails we've sent. It just hasn't changed in the Wordpress Media Library...

Comment: When you upload an img file to WordPress it creates several sizes automatically. One of those is a thumbnail size, which it uses in the Media Library. So while you replaced the fullsize image, you'll notice there are probably 3 or 4 other images in the same folder like so: `filename-150x150.jpg`, etc. These will of course still be the old image.

Comment: Have a look at [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). You can batch regenerate all image sizes or go to the media library and just regen that one image.

Comment: It looks like the main problem was that Chrome was caching all of my Wordpress images/thumbnails. Using Regenerate Thumbnails didn't fix the problem. I had to clear my cache in Chrome for everything to readjust.